# RactiveJS events on tripple mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ractivejs

I have a paging function since it's a little bit tricky to do it in the templates. The problem is that if I place it like this:

```
{{ paging( rows, limit, offset ) }}
```

It will obviously escape the output , so I tried with triple-stache and the output is as expected. But then, it wont detect `on-click` events anymore.. any suggestions ?

A workaround I thought about is setting `jQuery` to detect the `click` event on the `.pagination > li` but I just wanted to ask if there's any way RactiveJS can do that for me or I'm just missing something.

Have a great day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a partial if you want to add dynamic templating:

```
data: {
    foo: 'foo',
    paging: function(x){
        var template = '<li on-click="clicked()">' + x + '</li>';
        if (!this.partials.paging) {
            this.partials.paging = template;
        }
        else {
            this.resetPartial('paging', template);
        }
        return 'paging';
    }
},
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/fz7adjm4/