# Can Ractive events work in markup rendered with the triple-stash syntax?

Tags: ractivejs

If I have the following in my Ractive template:

```
<span on-click='handleClick'>click me</span>
```

Then I can listen for the click with this:

```
app.on({
    handleClick:function() {
        alert("clicked!") ;
    }
})
```

But lets say I have that same markup stored in a string variable called clicklyspan:

```
app.set("clicklyspan", "<span on-click='handleClick'>click me</span>")
```

and I render it in the template using the triple-stash syntax:

```
{{{clicklyspan}}}
```

The handleClick listener no longer gets fired. Is there anything I can do to force some kind of update to the rendered template so that the listener works? Say, after I do that `app.set()` call?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLzqmk7p/1/) demonstrating the problem.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Ractive, but I did some research and it seems you have to use `partials`, like this:

```
var app = new Ractive({
  el: 'container',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    myFunction: function() {
        var template = '<a on-click="handleClick">I can now be clicked as well!</a>';
        if (!this.partials.myFunction) {
            this.partials.myFunction = template;
        }
        else {
            this.resetPartial('myFunction', template);
        }
        return 'myFunction';
    }
  }
});
```

You will also need to use this instead of the triple mustache:

```
{{> myFunction() }}
```

Here's the corresponding [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrjuwzvv/1/).

Of course, replace `myFunction` with whatever name you like.

*Related question I found useful:*

[RactiveJS events on tripple mustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778586/ractivejs-events-on-tripple-mustache)

Comment: For anyone else with the same issue, there is also a good (but hard to find) example in the official Ractive docs [here](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/partials). Just scroll down to the *Partials on-the-fly* example.